# How to retrieve only queried objects from array in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My document has the following structure:

```
{
    "sku": "x",
    "prices": [{"code": 1}, {"code": 2}, {"code": 3}]
}
```

I'm trying to query only the objects inside prices array that have code 1 or 3:

```
db.my_coll.find({
    sku: "x"
}, {
    _id: 0,
    prices: {
        $elemMatch: {
            $or: [{code: 1}, {code: 3}]
        }
    }
})
```

But the result only retrieves the `code` 1:

```
{ "prices" : [ {"code" : 1} ] }
```

The result should be:

```
{ "prices" : [ {"code" : 1}, {"code": 3} ] }
```

How can i get only a specific object inside a array?

> the prices array has a lot of objects (100 at least)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) returns only first matching element, you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) with [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) instead:

```
db.my_coll.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { sku: "x" }
    },
    {           
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            prices: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$prices",
                    cond: {
                        $in: [ "$$this.code", [ 1, 3 ] ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            prices: { $ne: [] } // if you don't want to get empty arrays in result set
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: this empty $match/prices key is required? i've runned your query and it didn't retrieve nothing :/

Comment: @RafaAcioly the above query works. You can see it here and also why the last $match is needed: https://mongoplayground.net/p/l8UgiPzyjL2

Comment: Did u changed the collection name because @mickl is using `db.col` and u are using `db.my_coll` because this query works thats the only thing i can think of

Comment: I've modified my answer, changed collection name as @ShivamSood suggested. You can also remove the last `$match` if you're fine with empty arrays in your result set. @Akrion, thanks for providing mongo playground :)

Comment: i may have typed anything wrong before, it works now.  **i miss sql :-(**

Answer (score 0):

Another more old school way to do this and if you do not have `MongoDB 3.2` version (since [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) was introduced there) is via $unwind/$match/$group & $project:

```
db.my_coll.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$prices"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      sku: "x",
      "prices.code": {
        $in: [
          1,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      prices: {
        $push: "$prices"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      prices: 1
    }
  }
])
```

You can see the results here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/JQ4xRomk3VM

Overall the approach by `mickl` seems to be what you would want if you are on `MongoDB 3.2` and above.